# file_get_contents not working with facebook graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, file-get-contents

file_get_contents not working with following url (failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request)

`$token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=235326466577139&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fapps.facebook.com%2Flikeablephotos%2F&client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET&code=AQDFZbjpAUda8c_gz4wDDuBOVrsn0dApz3s8UA--7hFQIi1wb70-tDE56xXcCtDq-hV5UWzR5YEw_ozuGT24FLfvh9KnqHZ3xdn46P_KxYCf3DHJQA3AAu2ICHBqTk1-6fHTsl6FbagKz83H6dn15kkbKksajA4KcVIoPse5JbuBLlh6V5L1ANe8fzR94iH_SMU"`;

```
$response = file_get_contents($token_url);
```

but if you copy and paste the above URL into the browser address bar it works just fine! and returns:

```
access_token=AAADWBzZAyUvMBAL2Th6CRtxh2Up5soTCK8N4HJcy0ZBhQgJPxtZArKbuITISMoGLDxNiyeNW4GUZCBvJPeBTH6mx4v83ueUIAAYQJA1WrAZDZD&expires=5112501
```

but his similar URL (for a different user) also works:

```
$token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=235326466577139&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fapps.facebook.com%2Flikeablephotos%2F&client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET&code=AQC2kTEV96-1Cki2oYUhyzjH6yFe6AJRd1Q3G8fbUXW-IsLJUlactzSwCvGVBK6jh1tL-t7v6dOWJZzbkSYhk0n2z6BHQcpljWAdoXFGB5zLC4FgW8fmxT6hwdRIQOr2dZ95CD_q5yJuOUz_2DItUa3_FF9m2_TmFYGEbxPoiaF47YSTUuZp6g-8ffziJcKDAdo";
```

when using `file_get_contents`

Please help, thanks

Comment: That's kind of an old topic, but I ran into this problem too, and solved it this way: https wrappers were turned off on the hosting so i had to enable php_openssl

Comment: cURL can handle HTTPS without problem, while `file_get_contents()` may not work in some cases.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to file_get_contents have you considered using cURL. I use curl for alot of requests with great results and on fail it will not expose your client secret.

refer to http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

this code snippet is a standard for all my apps to get application access token.  Can be used for all api calls.

---

```
$app_access_token = GetCH();
function GetCH(){
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET&grant_type=client_credentials");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
if(substr($url,0,8)=='https://'){
    // The following ensures SSL always works. A little detail:
    // SSL does two things at once:
    //  1. it encrypts communication
    //  2. it ensures the target party is who it claims to be.
    // In short, if the following code is allowed, CURL won't check if the 
    // certificate is known and valid, however, it still encrypts communication.
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH,CURLAUTH_ANY);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);
}
$sendCH = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $sendCH;
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have been playing around with curl but can't get it to work with the url that was giving me the bad request, I've just tried your code for that url and it does not work either but returns:

Comment: Thanks @Shawn E Carter for your answer, I have been playing around with curl but can't get it to work with the url that was giving me the bad request, I've just tried your code for that url and it does not work either but returns: {"error":{"message":"Error validating verification code.","type":"OAuthException","code":100}} I need to use the original url

Comment: cont... which has now changed due to resetting the app to:    https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=235326466577139&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fapps.facebook.com%2Flikeablephotos%2F&client_secret=66946fa19cec760e5e747eafae1307ff&code=AQAeLmwImyd0oAi8VWtC4M-WXRvKvEltq9ER3rtwMx4lCu-9Khe-KGwK8Q9xt_FnrE-GnfkjA7d6Eo_ry2Ce_IKrtSfXfLhLvdFZ7ShxssF4FN0QlZeC9y3qJJ64nVpy_BJFIViioOZeEkxwxGrRpkMb-eplOoW78DK9vVjDMois2FGFQknLVJ9A9Y35HpQXn-g

Comment: the OAuth URL is always HTTPS. still valid in 2015.

Answer (score 2):

Finally found the answer, had the same issue..the problem is most likely because facebook's code that they give you has spaces in between the params. If you just copied and pasted from Facebook, you will get a HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request error. Put all the params on one line and remove all spaces and this should fix it. Worked for me. I know this is an older post but if you are having this problem let me know if it works for you!

Answer (score 0):

For debugging:

Take the actual string in $token_url and paste into a browser address field and see what happens.

You will get some back some json error code.

For me, it was the my token was expired.  Starting fresh request worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

same problem happened to me the problem was access token supplied with the URL was expired since access token have 1 hour validity ,so i created a new access token and it works again ,hope this info helps .