# Facebook API: /oauth/access_token not working

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I am trying to obtain a user access token from Facebook with the PHP-SDK. The server-side log-in process works great, redirecting to the correct page and providing `$code` too.

After the redirect (and checking whether `$code` exists) I then call the following API method to exchange `$code` for a user token (API parameters are suppressed here):

```
$fb->api('/oauth/access_token',array(
    'client_id'     => APP_ID,
    'client_secret' => APP_SECRET,
    'redirect_uri'  => REDIRECT_URI,
    'code'          => $code
));

$fb_token = $fb->getAccessToken();
echo $fb_token;
```

Unfortunately, all I get from this script is still the app token. In fact, reducing the script to just the following does not make any difference:

```
$fb_token_user = $fb->getAccessToken();
echo $fb_token_user;
```

So I assume it is all about the `/oauth/access_token` call which for some reason is not working or at least does no action. It does not return any errors either.

I have tried and tested several alternatives, such as the `get_file_contents()` method suggested in the Facebook tutorial as well as adding additional parameters to the above API call (e.g. `type=client_cred` and more), but never succeeding.

Does anybody see why the API call is not working? Is it the script or could it be some app setting on Facebook?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: your APP_ID and APP_SECRET are correct? On your app configurations do have the right url?

Comment: @fabio Both APP_ID and APP_SECRET are correct. As Site URL in the app configuration I have set https://www.domain.com/ with trailing slash, which should allow any document on the domain, right?

Comment: try changing it to the url that will receive the oauth response

Comment: @FabioAntunes - Still doesn't work, unfortunately. I guess it would return error if it was wrong, but it was worth a try. Could it have anything to do with permissions? I'm currently requesting `scope=publish_actions,manage_pages,create_event` as I would then like to use this user token to obtain a non-expiring page token.

Comment: Usually when you have the wrong url on your app configurations or if you have the wrong app_id or app_secret it doesn't return any token. Try using javascript SDK to the oauth thing, then use php SDK to grab the data from the user

Comment: @FabioAntunes - Thanks for your help! I was trying to avoid the need for a hybrid SDK implementation, though I would have definitely tried it hadn't I found the other solution in the meantime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solved!** The code in the question is still not working in spite of ever so many threads on this and other communities stating it does (oddly enough it seemed to work for [them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10877126/2201252)).

So I figured I had to go back to the `file_get_contents()` method as explained by [Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/server-side-login/) and it turns out this method was previously not working because `allow_url_fopen` is disabled on my server. Not wanting to undergo the risk of enabling it, I discovered [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) as a work-around.

And here is the working code:

```
// cURL Load Function
function cURLget ($ch_url) {
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$ch_url);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
  $ch_send = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  return $ch_send;
};

// Obtain User Token
$fb_token_get = cURLget("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token"
  . "?client_id=" . APP_ID
  . "&client_secret=". APP_SECRET
  . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode(REDIRECT_URI)
  . "&code=" . $CODE
);
$fb_token_params = null;
parse_str($fb_token_get,$fb_token_params);

// Print Token Data
echo "Token: " . $fb_token_params['access_token']
  . "<br />Expires: " . $fb_token_params['expires'];
```

Thanks to @FabioAntunes for trying to help me with the original code and to @ShawnECarter for his [script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10864928/2201252) for the cURL Load Function.

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled upon this problem today too. Seems my PHP SDK (v.3.2.2) offers a function that solves the problem: setExtendedAccessToken(). (Does pretty much the same thing: Calls graph's "/oauth/access_token" and exchanges the old token against a "long-lived" one).